# Google Sheets ARRAYFORMULA not copying form responses

Tags: google-sheets

So I have a form setup which sends data into a sheet labeled 'Form Responses'.

I have another sheet that mimics the column layout of 'Form Responses' but has formatting applied to it, (called 'Feedback') - Both in the same spreadsheet file.

In 'Feedback', I have the following formula to copy the form responses into the feedback sheet:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA('Form Responses'!$A2:$G2) // 7 columns
```

Upon keying in said formula, and filling in all the 1000 available rows, existing data is copied over and formatted neatly. Yay.

However, when new data is submitted via the form into 'Form Responses', the 'Feedback' sheet does not update. Instead, it appears that the rows are just... missing.

```
 Cell | Formula
 A9   | =ARRAYFORMULA('Form Responses'!$A9:$G9)
 A10  | =ARRAYFORMULA('Form Responses'!$A10:$G10) 
 A11  | =ARRAYFORMULA('Form Responses'!$A11:$G11) // Last row with data
 A12  | =ARRAYFORMULA('Form Responses'!$A13:$G13) // A12 formula missing
```

The formula for A12:G12 seems to have disappeared. This happens with all new form responses - If I have 3 new responses, it'll go from A11 to A15. And the 'Feedback' sheet won't update.

What's happening? Where (and why) is my formula usage wrong? Is there a different way altogether to dynamically copy form responses into a different sheet, and not just one-off?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this if you are simply copying to a new sheet.

> =query('Form Responses'!A:G, "SELECT * ")

**Syntax**
`QUERY(data, query, [headers])`

The `'Form Responses'!A:G,` is the `data` range of the source sheet that you would like to draw data from.

The `"Select * ",` is the `query` and will select everything within the range defined previously in the same order.

I did not know this when I first started using `Query` so I will share. If you want to select specific columns but reorder them plus leave other columns out, you can do this by getting specific with your `SELECT`

ie. You have Data in Columns `A:F` but you want to leave `D` and `F` out and put `E` before `C` in your new sheet, You can use this `"SELECT A,B,E,C"`

You can [read more about it here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) its quite powerful.

You can format the new sheet to your hearts delight and it will always update when you enter new data. As long as you have data in the range you've defined in the query.

Comment: Yeah, this works. It solves the problem, but do you have any insight into why ARRAYFORMULA was 'misbehaving', so to speak?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you were looking for originally with the `ArrayFormula`

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(Form Responses!A:A),Form Responses!A:G,))
```

This will iterate down column A and check if there is anything in it, if so then it will grab that row and display it, if not then do nothing.